# Laravel 7 - Class hash does not exist

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have a newly created Laravel application with Backpack installed in it. I am struggling to deploy it to Google Cloud for the past few days.

I'm using Laravel 7, I'm trying to deploy to Google cloud App Engine and getting `Class hash does not exist` error. Few times I've also gotten `Class view does not exist`.

I'm pretty sure that this is something to do with deployment environment rather than my changes. The reason for me to say this is, this morning I updated `backpack/crud` version and the application ran successfully after deployment.

So just to test, I deployed again without making any changes, zero files were uploaded and I ran into the same problem!

It would be great if someone can give me pointers to what I can try.

```
2020/07/09 23:42:46 [error] 20#20: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class hash does not exist in /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): ReflectionClass->__construct('hash')
#1 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(687): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('hash')
#2 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('hash', Array, true)
#3 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(633): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('hash', Array)
#4 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('hash', Array)
#5 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1280): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('hash')
#6 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/CreatesUserPro...PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class hash does not exist in /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805
```

My composer.json -

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "backpack/crud": "4.1.*",
        "backpack/permissionmanager": "^6.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage": "^2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "backpack/generators": "^3.1",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "composer clearcache",
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan cache:clear",
            "php artisan config:clear"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems more that the binding on the container for 'hash' wasn't set for some reason

Comment: Search the app folder for "use Hash;" I found one calling that is not being used, i just removed it and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run into a similar problem quite often.  Though not exactly the same, it may be similar enough that this will solve it for you.  For me it is usually a cache issue with the build.

If this happens after a composer update, and you forget to do `--no-dev` and then remove stuff on the next update, this error may occur.

**To Fix:**

Either the no-dev issue, or perhaps a general cache issue with the build, manually go into the bootstrap/cache folder & remove the files, especially the packages file.  Or, if you've set the environment as `DEV`, and you actually didn't pull in the dev packages, go back and composer update (without no-dev)

Alternatively, if you're still stuck, you can try to update composer with no scripts and then install.
In my case, once it was still trying to load debugbar.

Comment: I've not installed anything using `--no-dev`.

I noticed that `config.php` is missing after my deployment in `bootstrap/cache`. Could this be the issue and what can I do to force it to be regenerated?

Comment: Answering my own question, `config.php` is not required in `bootstrap/cache`.

Comment: The `--no-dev` is what gets me.  But the issue is actually a failure in the caching system following a composer install -- not necessarily from `--no-dev`.  In either case, if I delete **packages.php**  this solves the issue in 90% of the cases for me.  If this didn't work for you, it may be an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I added `bcrypt` function into my config file. Resolved by removing it of course.

Make sure you do not have executable functions in your config folder members.